# How does Nikita give out her captive location in episode Cat and Mouse?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-femme-nikita

In the show La femme Nikita, there is a classic doppelganger trope in S03E07(Cat and Mouse), where Nikita has been kidnapped by an organization who then plants a doppelganger in the *section* who she is supposed to guide in real-time to deceive them.

I can't figure out how exactly Nikita gave them her location so they can rescue her. I can understand how and why they might figure out the double isn't really her. 
The only reason I can think of it could be her tracking implant, but it's not mentioned at all. And probably they can block such scans since in S04E18 where she is held by a crazy guy in his basement, *Madeline* says such organizations can block IR and *RF* scans.

I really wish they would have given the answer at the end when the guy in charge ask her how she gave Section her location. Any ideas how it could've happened?

Comment: Two incidents may have no connection since Madeline says such organizations's ability to block IR and RF, but incident you mention happens way before **(in season 3)** . So it could be Nikita's implant that leads to the rescue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the episode just wanted to leave that in the air, before we knew of their implants. I hoped there was some hidden clue I missed.

Answer (score 2):

What Dominic asks her in the end is "You found a way to let them know? How?"

While I can see how this can be misconstrued as to location, I believe that it is directed more towards letting Section know about the doppelganger. 1) She wasn't shot on the mission. 2) Michael noticed that she wasn't sniffling any more and asked her about her cold, and she seemed oblivious to it. 3) She was wearing glasses. Michael questioned her about them. Then Nikita pushed Abby into suggesting a romantic engagement with Michael on level 4. That, I believe, is when the dam busted.

I think Michael went back and talked to Operations and they brought Birkoff in and found/traced the transmissions from Abby's glasses and comms back to Dominic's lair. They sent Michael to have sex with Abby while a team was sent to the lair, and when they were ready, they called "Jaques".